# CSS get parent elements attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i just ran into this problem. Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<article data-color='#123456'>
    <header>...</header>
    <a href='#'>Lorem ipsum</a>...
    ...
</article>
```

So I have an element with a custom color attribute. I want to have the header have it as a background color, and the link as a color (the color is either randomly generated or user-defined). Is there a way to do this is CSS alone? (I am aware that jQuery would do this without a problem, but I'd like to kepp things as pretty as possible, not using Javascript for styling alone.)

Comment: If you specifically don't want the answer in javascript/jQuery why tag it as such? Are you also looking for that answer if just css is not possible?

Comment: No, there's no way to generate random colors in CSS without javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an attribute selector in your CSS:

```
article[data-color="#123456"] header {
    background-color: "#123456";
}

article[data-color="#123456"] a {
    color: "#123456";
}
```

However, this assumes you can enumerate the `data-color` attributes in your CSS. If it's generated dynamically and can take any value, you can't do it in CSS -- it doesn't have variables or back-references.

Comment: I don't like this answer purely because you're writing the value twice

Comment: the solution to that is to use something like `LESS` to give more structure to your CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately CSS cannot do this. the JS is relatively simple though:

```
$('article').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('color');
}).each(function() {
    var $el = $(this), color = $el.data('color');
    $el
        .find('header').css('background-color', color).end()
        .find('a').css('color', color);        
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4bt4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
article[data-color="#123456"] header {
    background-color: attr(data-color color);
}

article[data-color="#123456"] a {
    color:  attr(data-color color);
}
```

***UPDATE***

The first answer is incorrect, it doesn't work.
Do this rather:

```
article[data-color="#123456"] header {
    background-color: "#123456";
}

article[data-color="#123456"] a {
    color:  "#123456";
}
```

Comment: I tried this with my answer, but it won't work because the data-attribute is on the parent.  Your two rules will look for a `data-color` attribute on the `header` and `a` tags respectively; whereas, it is actually on the `article`.

Comment: I would do the whole thing in jQuery if I were you.

Comment: Or change `attr(data-color color)` to `"#123456"`